# App Communication on Windows IoT

Tags: windowsiot

i want to run 2 different BackgroundTasks - one for the communication with my arduino - and one for the communication with other devices by using a webservice. These tasks should be able to write and read from ONE database. But my problem is, that the Windows.Storage.ApplicationData does not provide the SharedLocalFolder. It is null, if I want to use it. Is there any other way where i can store my database that both BackgroundTask can connect to it?

Additionally I found now this path:(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.GetPublisherCacheFolder(...)). This look very interesting, but if i want to use it I cant write there. I think, because the resolved file path does not exist..

Any other ideas?

Sincerely,

Answer (score 0):

**App2App Communication via WebServer (Blinky WebServer):**
You can refer Microsoft's IoT sample provided for [Blinky Webserver](https://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/samples/BlinkyWebServer.htm) which also depicts the concept of App2App Communication. But you need to read it thoroughly to modify and reuse it up-to your expectation.

Right now I have no experience about Windows IoT and database. Once I got my hands on it, I'll update.